# Real-Time Data with Jinja

Tags: python, django

I was using Django to display some data from my database, Jinja was so easy to use to place every string where i wanted on my css template.
i was looking on the internet how to make it liveStream or real-time data display and everywhere i look there is only javascript.
i dont know anything about javascript and was looking for help someone to send me to the right direction how i can make this happen as easy is possible

this is a code example from my project:

```
 {% load django_template_maths %}
        {% block content %}
        <ul class="listitems">
            {% for s in stats %}
                {% if s.0 == "37" and s.1 == "00" %}
                <li data-position="0">
                {% else %}
                <li data-position="{{ s.0 }}.{{ s.1 }}">
                {% endif %}
```

Comment: This is solely javascript task, that's why javascript is made. Django is not using jinja templating engine. Please remove jinja tag.

Comment: web browser has to run JavaScript code which will periodically ask web server for new data, get it and update HTML on page.

Comment: You can try with keyword `StreamingHttpResponse`. There might be something you really need but be careful when using that.